# Создание проекта в Dev C++ 5

Tags: ide, c++

Скажите, пожалуйста, как начать новый проект в Dev C++ 5? Еще скажите, я создаю программу в Dev C++ 5, нажимаю "скомпилировать", после я нажимаю "выполнить", появляется окно, там написано: "Файл не откомпилирован".Что мне делать? Я новичок в C++. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для институтских лабораторок (задачек) проект, в принципе, можно и не создавать - Dev C++ и просто исходный файл скомпилирует в консольную программу. У меня как-то раз была похожая проблема. Такая проблема может быть, если Вы используете портабельный Dev C++.